# How to do the createJS equivalent of gotoAndPlay() and stop()

Tags: flash, createjs, easeljs

Here's the scenario:
I am creating an infographic interactive animation which allows the user to virtually set up a tripod, interact with a virtual camera, etc. I need the timeline to stop when an arrow points where the user should click. Then the timeline should resume playing upon clicking the tripod (A movieClip) (the tripod also animates and then the view switches to first-person with the camera). Currently, the animation just plays forever, without stopping whatsoever to allow user interaction. Here is my createJS code so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CreateJS export from birdsofprey-anim9c</title>

    <script src="http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.createjs.com/tweenjs-0.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.createjs.com/movieclip-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.createjs.com/preloadjs-0.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="birdsofprey-anim9c.js"></script>

    <script>
    var canvas, stage, exportRoot;

    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        images = images||{};

        var manifest = [
            {src:"images/Bitmap1.png", id:"Bitmap1"},
            {src:"images/Bitmap2.png", id:"Bitmap2"},
            {src:"images/Scene_1.jpg", id:"Scene_1"}
        ];

        var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
        loader.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
        loader.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
        loader.loadManifest(manifest);
    }

    function handleFileLoad(evt) {
        if (evt.item.type == "image") { images[evt.item.id] = evt.result; }
    }

    function handleComplete() {
        exportRoot = new lib.birdsofpreyanim11a();

        stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
        stage.addChild(exportRoot);
        tripodleg = new lib.LEFT_LEG_MC;
        stage.addChild(tripodleg);
        stage.update();

        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(24);
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick",f);
        function f(e){
        //var t=this;
        //t.stop();
        //exportRoot.stop();
        var delay = 4000;
        var startTime=createjs.Ticker.getTime();
        createjs.Ticker.getMeasuredFPS();
        if(createjs.Ticker.getMeasuredFPS == 6){
           exportRoot.stop();
           tripodleg.onclick = function(){
               exportRoot.gotoAndPlay(90);
           }
           //exportRoot.gotoAndPlay(90);
            createjs.Ticker.removeEventListener("tick",f);
            }
        }
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
    }

    </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="init();" style="background-color:#D4D4D4">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="550" height="540" style="background-
    color:#ffffff"></canvas>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks in advance, StackOverflow and for the expertise of the super coders they're affiliated with! -qs
**[EDIT]** Updated my code again this time adding an instance of my tripod MovieClip to the stage via **addChild();** and stopping the timeline via **exportRoot.stop();** exportRoot isn't stopping, any clues? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are talking about the line:

```
function handlClick(){
    mc.play(2);
}
```

If so, just use `gotoAndPlay(2)` instead of `play`. EaselJS was initially based on the ActionScript language, so it mirrors a lot of that functionality. Check out the [MovieClip docs](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/MovieClip.html).

```
function handlClick(){
    mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

One thing to note: What is `createjs.Ticker.tick` in your `handlTick` method? There is no tick property, only a "tick" event. The if statement this is in will never be `true`. What are you trying to do with that code exactly? Are you looking for the click handler to be added when the main clip reaches frame 30? Or after 30 "ticks"? Either way, this will do nothing.

Hope that helps.

**[EDIT based on updates]**

It looks like you changed it to use `gotoAndPlay`, but there are a few problems:

You are calling a global `gotoAndPlay` function (which doesn't exist) instead of targeting a MovieClip instance. If your main timeline has the frame you want to go to, use `exportRoot.gotoAndPlay(90);`.

Next, you are calling `this.stop()`. Your event listener is anonymous (which is fine), but that means that `this` is `Window`. Again, there is no global `stop` method -- so you should call it on the timeline you wish to stop. In this case, it's probably `exportRoot.stop()`.

Cheers,

Comment: You mentioned: "There is no tick property, only a "tick" event." Yes that was what I suspected as well, thanks for the update.

Comment: You said: "Are you looking for the click handler to be added when the main clip reaches 30?" ...Exactly. I wanted the WHOLE timeline to stop at frame 30, not an MC on the timeline. I looked at the example for Ticker.setPause(true), but its just way over my head. Maybe set a var for FPS to tell Ticker to sync to the frame rate of the timeline, right? Thanks for cluing me in to those errors, please let me know about how to make the stop(); action I am trying to create at frame 30. Again, any help would be appreciated, Thanks a million. -qs.

Comment: Its still not stopping. Any suggestions? Thanks, -qs

Comment: Edited answer above.

Comment: That sounds like a decent workaround. I changed the code in my createJS **.HTML** file. Now it is just stopping and clicking after it stops does nothing. Do you know the link to the exportRoot docs where I could see a list all of its associated methods? Thanks again Lanny. -qs

Comment: The `exportRoot` is just a MovieClip that represents your main timeline (frames, symbols, scripts). You can see it in your exported code. It is equivalent of the `_root` in ActionScript. http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/MovieClip.html

Comment: Thanks, I simply need to (at a certain frame) stop the animation. Push a button in the animation and have the timeline start back up as a side effect. Thanks again,